# Codeigniter: Call to a member function result_array() on a non-object

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using Codeigniter to build a webapp and I received this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function result_array() on a 
non-object in /var/www/application/controllers/people.php on line 29
```

This is the people.php class:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

function People() {

}

function view($id) {
    echo "Hello world " . $id;
}

function all() {
    $this->load->model('people_model', '', TRUE);
    $allContacts = $this->people_model->get_all_contacts();
    $results = array();
    foreach ($allContacts->result_array() as $row) {
        $eachrow = array("personID"=>$row['personID'],"fName"=>$row['fName'],"lName"=>$row['lName'],"phoneNumber"=>"",
            "emailAddress"=>$row['emailAddress'],"address"=>$row['address'],"city"=>$row['city'],"state"=>$row['state'],"zip"=>$row['zip']);
        $results = push_array($results, $eachrow);
    }
    foreach ($results as $row) {
        $phoneData = $this->people_model->get_phone_by_id($row['personID']);
        $phoneNumbers = "";
        foreach ($phoneData->result_array() as $row2) {
            $phoneNumbers = $row2['type'] . " " . $row2['phoneNumber'] . " " . $row2['extension'];
        }
        $results['phoneNumber'] = $phoneNumbers;
    }

    $data['title']="Page Title Goes Here";
    $data['username']="Your Username";

    $this->load->view('header', $data);
    $this->load->view('people_results', $results);
    $this->load->view('footer');
}
}
```

Here is the people_model class:

```
function __construct()
{
    // Call the Model constructor
    parent::__construct();
}

function get_all_contacts() {
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM person');
    return $query->result();
}

function get_phone_by_id($id) {
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM phoneNumber WHERE personID = '.$id);
    return $query->result();
}
}
```

The only thing I might question in database.php is if the hostname needs a port number, but I don't think that helped when I tried it.

I just tried adding (based on similar question in side bar)

```
$this->mydb = $this->load->database('realDB', TRUE);
```

to the people_model and changing the db to mydb and received this error:

```
You have specified an invalid database connection group.
```

and this is my line in database.php:

```
$db['default']['database'] = 'realDB';
```

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since get_all_contacts is already using the result() function in your model, you can't also use the result_array() function in your controller.  result_array() would be a method of the $query object.  The quick and dirty way to get this working(which might break other stuff if its also using the get_all_contacts method) would be to change your get all contacts function to the following:

```
function get_all_contacts() {
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM person');
    return $query;
}
```

however, if you want to be smarter about it and not risk breaking other stuff, you can pass a param from the controller, and only return query if its set like so:

**REVISED CONTROLLER LINE****

```
$allContacts = $this->people_model->get_all_contacts(true);
```

**REVISED MODEL CODE**

```
function get_all_contacts($special = false) {
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM person');
    if($special)
    {
        return $query;
    }
    return $query->result();
}
```