# How to convert named inner join query to code-igniter syntax?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, codeigniter

I have the following query

```
$query = $this->db->query(
        'SELECT ii.json

        FROM inventory ii
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT json, MAX(id) as MAX_ID
            FROM inventory
            GROUP BY business_unit
        ) group_json ON ii.id = group_json.MAX_ID

        INNER JOIN business_units 
        ON ii.business_unit = business_units.id'
    );

    return $query->result_array();
```

We've had to migrate to a MSSQL test server and unfortunately the syntax is incorrect. To avoid this in the future I want to convert this to the CodeIgniter typed query.

Can anyone show me what this query would look like in CodeIgniter, I've tried a few things but I'm not getting anywhere close.

Comment: Can you make it a stored procedure?

Comment: What about the syntax is correct?  It looks like it should work on MS SQL Server, MySQL, and Oracle just fine.

Comment: I've tested it and we get an error after GROUP BY. I would like to see the CodeIgniter SQL equivalent though.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ii.json
FROM inventory ii
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT json, MAX(id) as MAX_ID
    FROM inventory
    GROUP BY business_unit, json    --<-- "json" needs to be in GROUP BY
) group_json                           -- Since it is in SELECT but not
ON ii.id = group_json.MAX_ID           -- contained in any aggregate function
INNER JOIN business_units 
ON ii.business_unit = business_units.id
```

if you use any aggregate function(MAX, MIN, AVG, SUM, COUNT)  in your `SELECT` any other columns that are not contained in any aggregate function in that select,  must go in `GROUP BY` clause of your query.

Comment: Fatal error:  Call to a member function result_array() on a non-object

Comment: You also have `business_unit` in your group by clause ??? are you sure you want to group by your result by this column ??

Comment: im not PHP guy have a look here maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18347028/codeigniter-call-to-a-member-function-result-array-on-a-non-object at least your group by error has been eliminated now you are getting some PHP related error.